# Errors in building ceplayit (directshow player sample)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, directshow, media, linker-errors

I tried to build the CEPlayit files (of DirectShow player samples). I added them to a smart device project based on the sdk for my device (named TEMP). I am using MFC in visual Studio 2005. However the following errors occurred:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IBasicAudio   vidwindow.obj
>   Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_OverlayMixer    ceplayit.obj
>   Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IBaseFilter   ceplayit.obj
>   Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaEventEx ceplayit.obj
>   Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IBasicVideo   ceplayit.obj
>   Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IVideoWindow  ceplayit.obj
>   Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaPosition    ceplayit.obj
>   Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaSeeking ceplayit.obj
>   Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaControl ceplayit.obj
>   Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_FilterGraph ceplayit.obj
>   Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IGraphBuilder ceplayit.obj
>   Error   12  fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals    TEMP

I read that I need to link `strmbase.lib` to my project but I think I am unable to correctly do this and the errors persist.
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem, the .libs strmiids.lib and strmbase.lib had to be linked. I did not not know how to do this and in case there is anyone else like me:
in project properties->configuration prop->linker->general... additional library directories, add the path where the .lib files are, which for me was C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600\TEMP\Lib\ARMV4I, where TEMP was the name of the SDK i was using.

In project properties->configuration prop->linker->input->additional dependencies, add the .libs you require separated by a space: strmbase.lib strmiids.lib

and it built successfully!